# How to retrieve Date column from the table without Time?

Tags: c#, mysql, date, asp.net-core, dapper

I have table names ***Student*** with a column named ***OrderDate*** of type Date in MySQL.

[image]

My Web API Code is below

```
public class Student
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}

 string sql = "SELECT OrderDate FROM Student";
 using (IDbConnection conn= new MySqlConnection(connString))
 {
      return  connection.Query<Student>(sql)).ToList();
  }
```

The above code is retuning the order date as

```
  "orderDate": "2019-10-30T00:00:00"
```

The expected date value is "2019-10-30"

I tried different approaches (updating the sql, change the DateTime  to DateOnly etc.)

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(OrderDate, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM Student;
```

Please let me know the how to get date in YYYY-MM-DD format with out the time part.

Comment: `DateTime` in C# always has a time component. If you're using .NET 6 you could try out `DateOnly`, though I've not tested that with Dapper, nor with System.Text.Json.

Comment: Dapper seems not supporting DateOnly

Comment: I think you might be focused on the wrong area of code. You focusing on what you are getting from the DB (which as DateTime will always have the time). You need to focus on your Output code and providing it with a Format string (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings). So where ever you are outputting OrderDate, do something like `item.OrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: Thanks. That will make sense. The format can be done in the client side.

Comment: *The above code is retuning the order date as* It seems that you confuse the value itself and its representation during its output. MySQL returns date only. But value receiving datatype contains timepart, hence it obtains zero value, and complete received value is datetime. This won't effect during the data processing, but effects the output (printing the value on the screen) - and you must format the value to needed form during the output.

Comment: Does your front end really care about the 00:00:00?

Comment: Thanks again. This should be done at the client side

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` in your student class.

Example:

```
public class Student
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
}
```

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-data-model-class).

After that run your app and see the output.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and mark the solution.